# Calculating descriptive statistics for grouped data with class intervals in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe that goes like this:

```
    age     population
  (10,15]     13070
  (16,25]     415195
  (26,35]    1061167
  (36,45]     827648
  (46,55]     379402
  (56,65]     258227
  (66,80]     192331
```

I've actually managed to do the necessary calculations to obtain the descriptive measures about the age of the said-so population(e.g., mean, median, mode, quartiles, standard deviation, among others) but only when manually doing the necessary mathematical process, and I wish I could do it in an easier, cleaner way. Let's say I'd want to calculate the descriptive measures for age in this same data frame again, in a cleaner, easier way - how should I do it?

You can reproduce the dataframe by using:

```
age_data = data.frame(age = c("(10,15]", "(16,25]", "(26,35]", "(36,45]", "(46,55]", "(56,65]", "(66,80]"),
                    population = c("13070", "415195", "1061167", "827648", "379402", "258227", "192331"))
```

The desired output would be basically what you would get by applying the formulae for descriptive statistics for grouped data with class intervals. For instance, in mean, you'd apply:

M=∑f×xn

Where:

f = The frequency of each class

x = The width of each class

n = The sum of the frequencies

(formula reference: https://mrdwab.github.io/mathrrr/reference/grouped_functions.html)

And the output, for that case, should be something around 39.20.

Although I can, with the mentioned library, calculate mean, median and mode, I'd still need to calculate quartiles, standard deviation and kurtosis, which are considerably complicated to calculate without an in-built function.

It's important to add that the original database where I got the data from had the first and last ages ranges postulated as "up to 15 years" and "66 years or more", so I had to arbitrarily consider an interval that I considered to make sense.

Comment: I have [some grouped functions](https://mrdwab.github.io/mathrrr/reference/grouped_functions.html) in the [mathrrr package](https://mrdwab.github.io/mathrrr/index.html). Assuming your "population" column is numeric (it isn't presently) you'd be able to do something like `with(x, grouped_median(population, age, ",", trim = "cut"))`.

Comment: You want to calculate mean age?  If you have three 15 year olds  but it's recoded at population 3 in (10,15]. You've lost information to calculate the true mean of 15. If you assume they are between 10 and 15, you'd likely underestimate. Do you want to model the underlying continuous distribution some how? How accurate do you need these values to be?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using the numbers with the wrong formatting. I've edited the question to correct the numbers, insert a reproductible dataframe, and explain more or less the desired output, using the formulae provided by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Did you use `cut` to get data in a format that you currently have? We probably would need data before you did that. We can get range out of the string "(10,15]" but it is not the best approach so it would be better if we can get the data before you got it into this stage.

Comment: @RonakShah the original data I've got these numbers from was already divided by range